# Raster Combining in batch using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am trying to combine two different raster files using a loop, with the following script.

```
import  arcpy
import os

thectr = 0
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\TerAqua'
Terra_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MOD*")
Aqua_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MYD*")
output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output""\\"+ str(thectr)+'.tif'
matches = 0
for item1 in Terra_Rasters:
    for item2 in Aqua_Rasters:
        print item1
        print item2
        if item1.endswith(item2[32:51]):
            print "Match"
            arcpy.gp.Con_sa(item1,item2,output,item1,"\"Value\" =8")
        else:
            print "No"
            matches = matches+1
```

I need to use a loop for the output files name, I faced the following error.

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 7, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   510, in      return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 000872: Output raster: Dataset D:\BRB Snow
>   Cover\Sample\output0.tif already exists and cannot be overwritten
>   since the Overwrite existing datasets option is disabled.

Comment: No, the files are time series with some missing days, I need to use the name from one of input files

Comment: I want the output name be same as item1 or either item2. I put above code to my script. I got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here:

1) `output` will always be `D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\output0.tif` in your script. You are not changing it anywhere. If this is the expected behaviour (which I suspect is not) and you want to overwrite that file, simply write `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`.

2) If you want to change the output name and increase it by 1 (which I assume is what you're after), modify your code so each time `arcpy.gp.Con_sa()` is executed, `output` is changed beforehand. It could look something like this:

```
import  arcpy
import os

thectr = 0
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\TerAqua'
Terra_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MOD*")
Aqua_Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MYD*")
matches = 0
for item1 in Terra_Rasters:
    for item2 in Aqua_Rasters:
        print item1
        print item2
        if item1.endswith(item2[32:51]):
            print "Match"
            output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output""\\"+ str(thectr)+'.tif'
            arcpy.gp.Con_sa(item1,item2,output,item1,"\"Value\" =8")
            thectr += 1  # here you increase the variable by one each time Con is executed
        else:
            print "No"
            matches = matches+1
```

One of your comments says you want to match either `item1` or `item2` name in the output. In this case, simply change the `output` line to:

`output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output""\\"+ str(item1)+'.tif'`

3) `output` string could be more readable. Consider changing it to something like:

`output = r'D:\BRB Snow Cover\Sample\output{}.tif'.format(thectr)`

4) You are doing a nested loop here. Assuming `i` is the number of elements in `Terra_rasters` and `j` is the number of elements in `Aqua_rasters`, you'll end up executing `i` * `j` loops. If this is not what you are trying to do, but instead you are trying to execute `i` loops (I assume both lists have the same number of elements) and want to access both rasters (Terra and Aqua) at a time, you can use the `zip()` function in only one loop:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(Terra_Rasters, Aqua_Rasters):
   print item1
   print item2
```

Comment: The output = "D:\\BRB Snow Cover\\Sample\\output""\\"+ str(item1)+'.tif' is exactly what I need.